# Running a background task in PCF via IHostedService using .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, pcf, steeltoe

I wanted to peform a background task using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1 in .net core 2.1 and needs to host in PCF. When I run locally everything works fine. My implementation of IHostedService is getting called after Startup activites and I am able to terminate the application gracefully via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=aspnetcore-2.1. But when I host in PCF, I am getting below error

```
2018-11-09T18:27:35.359+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [OUT] Finished executing task!
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Permission denied
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at DlqProcessingApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\GitRepos\DeadLetterQueueProcessingTask\Program.cs:line 72
2018-11-09T18:27:35.365+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [ERR] at DlqProcessingApp.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
2018-11-09T18:27:35.381+05:30 [APP/TASK/execute-dlqprcoessing-task/0] [OUT] Exit status 134
```

I am registering IHostedService like below in my Startup.cs

```
     public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {

                 // Add management endpoint services
                services.AddCloudFoundryActuators(Configuration);
                services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, DlqProcessingHostedService>();

My implementation looks like below

    public class DlqProcessingHostedService : IHostedService
        {
            private readonly IApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

            private readonly ILogger<DlqProcessingHostedService> _logger;

            private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

            public DlqProcessingHostedService(IApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
                IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
                ILogger<DlqProcessingHostedService> logger)
            {
                _appLifetime = appLifetime;
                _logger = logger;
                _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            }

            public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var he = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HealthEndpoint>();
                    var worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorker>();
                    CheckStartupHealth(he);
                    await worker.ProcessDlxMessages();
                }
                _appLifetime.StopApplication();
            }

            public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Finished executing task!");
            }
```

Btw, if i am using generic host https://jmezach.github.io/2017/10/29/having-fun-with-the-.net-core-generic-host/ instead of WebHost, this is working fine. So basically I would like to know whether an IHostedService implementation is having  any issue with WebHost in PCF environment(It is working fine locally though). I am using the below packages and targeting a cflinuxfs2 stack. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.ConnectorCore" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore" Version="2.1.1" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

Here is my Program.cs

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)

        {

            //var host = new HostBuilder()
            //.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            //{
            //    var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
            //    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            //    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            //    config.AddCommandLine(args);
            //    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false);
            //    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, false);
            //    config.AddCloudFoundry();
            //})
            //.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            //{
            //    ConfigureServices(services, hostContext.Configuration);
            //})
            //.ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logBuilder) =>
            //{
            //    logBuilder.ClearProviders();
            //    logBuilder.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            //    logBuilder.AddDynamicConsole();
            //    if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            //    {
            //        logBuilder.AddDebug();
            //    }
            //});
            //await host.RunConsoleAsync();

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished executing task!");
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
           WebHost
           .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
           {
               config.AddCloudFoundry();
           })
           .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logBuilder) =>
           {
               logBuilder.ClearProviders();
               logBuilder.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
               logBuilder.AddDynamicConsole();
               if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
               {
                   logBuilder.AddDebug();
               }
           }).Build();
```

Comment: This error message looks related to port binding - can you also share your program.cs?

Comment: What address are you trying to connect in **CheckStartupHealth**? I think you run your app as administrator in your local computer. What about your server user? Does it have required permission?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate this with a basic sample based on what you've provided so far, but [this](https://github.com/TimHess/hostedservice) works fine on PCF for me - the error is likely coming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: Thanks for responding. My manifest looks like below applications:
- name: hostedservice
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  stack: cflinuxfs2
  buildpacks:
    - dotnet-core_buildpack_current
  instances: 0
  no-route: true
  services:
   - syslog-drain. Also I am trying to run the app via the command cf run-task hostedservice "dotnet hostedservice.dll "Test2" "Test3"" --name execute-dlqtask. I am still getting the same error. Tried with your sample app

Comment: Oh, that you're running with `cf run-task` changes things a bit - there's no assigned port in that case as far as I know, which would explain why you'd see port binding errors. You could try something like this: https://github.com/macsux/EFMigrate/blob/master/CFTasksExtensions.cs

We haven't included such an extension in Steeltoe quite yet, but that example can be executed with the command `cf run-task efmigrate './EFMigrate cftask=migrate'`

Comment: I checked your sample. So here we are skipping WebHost.Run() if initiated via cf run-task. Main motivation behind to run via Webhost was to perform HealthCheck(since CF actuators are supported only with WebHost). Another workaround, I found was to perform everything in Startup.cs(Healthcheck + actual task) without leveraging IHostedService. I am worried whether this is a good approach since I am performing all these(could be time consuming enough to create a timeout) in application bootstrap without leveraging IHostedService.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do... It might help to explain what this app is supposed to accomplish.

If you want a long-running app that includes healthchecks, it should use WebHost.
If you want an app that starts, does its thing and then stops, GenericHost should be fine (just have it log status updates as it goes).
If you want both a long-running app and an administrative task for special occasions with it (like db migrate), use cf run-task with something like the extension shared above

Comment: I will say the second one " If you want an app that starts, does its thing and then stops, GenericHost should be fine (just have it log status updates as it goes)". Along with this, I would like to perform a HealthCheck with CF actuator endpoints something like "private HealthCheckResult CheckStartupHealth(HealthEndpoint he)
        {
            var health = he.Invoke();
             return health;
        }". Here HealthEndpoint I can inject via constructor. But this is not possible if I use GenericHost